# Struggling to line two raster layers up with one another

Tags: georeferencing

I have a UAV survey of an agricultural trial site and I'm trying to analyze the imagery in QGIS.

I've been working on a multispectral .tif file and I've recently recieved a DSM (digital surface model) layer that I'm trying to import. The issue I'm facing is that the two layers don't quite line up with each other (they aren't far out but the surveys weren't done using RTK so they're a few feet out).

In the perfect world I'd simply just manually move the layer as it doesn't need to be perfectly accurate. However, that doesn't seem to be an option in QGIS so I've been told that I need to use the georeferancing tool.

Considering that the RGB layer is already where I want to it be, I've imported the DSM into "Georeferancer", and tried to join add points by clicking on GCPs in the DSM layer and then clicking the corresponding point on the RGB layer.

I then ran the tool but the points are literally miles apart. The image below should give you an idea.

[image]

These are my setting..

[image]

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. I don't actually need perfect real world coordinates, I just need to two images to line up with each other.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:
I think it might be a bug with this version? The meter coordinates put me in the middle of the sea but the deg, min coordinates are exactly where they should be. It looks like georeferanes works off of the meter coordinates?